# Eslint does not allow static class properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, class-fields

I'm current developing an API on Node 12.14.1 and using Eslint to help me write the code.
Unfortunately it does not allow me to set **static class properties** as shown below:

```js
class AuthManager {
  static PROP = 'value'
}
```

The following error is given: `Parsing error: Unexpected token =eslint`

Static class properties are already supported on JS and on Node.
**How can this rule be disable?**

I also have the following `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "globals": {
      "Atomics": "readonly",
      "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2018,
      "sourceType": "module"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

ESLint v8 now supports static class properties natively: https://eslint.org/blog/2021/10/eslint-v8.0.0-released

parserOptions ecmaVersion should be set to 13, 2022, or "latest" to enable the support.

Add this to your **.eslint.(cjs | json | js)**

```
{
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2022,
  }
}
```

Comment: As of v8 being released, this is now the 'right' answer.

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the same error on 8.6.0. Not sure if I'm the only one but if anyone reads this, know that you are not...

Comment: FWIW, I ended up having to use `@babel/eslint-parser` as specified in other answers. Was trying to avoid using babel anywhere. But, at least it still works.

Comment: Here is the configuration you need to add in your eslintrc config file (for a JSON file):

{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  }
}

Comment: I tried this as I'm using `@typescript-eslint/parser` but does not work. using `eslint@8.11.0`

Comment: I'm confirming that it works in with `node 12`, `eslint 8.15`. I just added exactly the lines that need to be added to .eslint.cjs

Comment: If you are targeting Node.js 14, do not set `ecmaVersion` to `2022`. Only some of ES2022's features have been implemented in Node.js 14.

Answer (score 44):

ESLint with its default parser does not support class fields syntax for now. You can solve the problem by changing the configured parser to `babel-eslint`.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-eslint
```

```
// eslintrc.json
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  ...
}
```

Eslint's default parser, Espree, does not support class fields because that syntax is currently stage 3, and that it is decided that only stage 4 proposals are to be supported in Espree.

Comment: Thanks! After setting `babel-eslint` the problem was solved.

Comment: `babel-eslint` is now `@babel/eslint-parser`.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static static is supported since node 6.
I'm using node 14, the latest stable LTS version. It is not pretty clear for me what is the reason for ESLint to not support it yet.

Comment: @Kostanos according to [TC39 Finished Proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md), Class Properties is a finished proposal and is included in ES2022. At the meantime, ESLint 7.x offically supports up to [ES2020](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/tree/v7.32.0#what-ecmascript-versions-does-eslint-support). This is why you have to use `@babel/eslint-parser`.
Babel ESLint Parser covers all experimental syntax ([lists here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)) that ESLint default parser doesn't support.

Answer (score 8):

As of now, I had to use these configs

`.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
  ],
  parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    babelOptions: {
      configFile: './.babelrc',
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // needed to support spread in objects
  },
  plugins: ['@babel'],
};
```

`.babelrc`

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

For which I had to install:

```sh
npm i -D @babel/preset-env
npm i -D @babel/eslint-parser
npm i -D @babel/eslint-plugin
npm i -D @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties
```

Notice that the `@babel` modules above are the only `@babel` modules in my `package.json`.

Answer (score 7):

you need to install `@babel/eslint-parser`:

```
yarn add --dev @babel/eslint-parser
```

And have the parser in your `.eslintrc.yml` for instance:

```
parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"
```