# Fix ESLint error around class variable definition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm getting an `eslint` error on this ES6 declaration of a class variable.  Can someone suggest either a better syntax, or what eslint rule I need to add or change.

error: `ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token =`

```js
export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false, error: null };
  updateHasErrorsToFalse = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasError: false,
    }));
  }; ...
```

Here is my .eslintrc.json

```json
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not an ES6 class if it uses class fields

Comment: this is the correct answer that solves my issue above.  Not the one referencd.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046847/eslint-does-not-allow-static-class-properties